# Web speech API grammar

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

Can somebody please tell me what this

```
 const grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghost | white | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow ;'
```

line means from the follwoing?

```
const grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghost | white | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow ;'
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition()
const speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList()
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1)
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList
```

If i want to incorporate my own grammar what changes to this line do I need to make?

Comment: What kind of grammar do you want to have? Single words like here with colors?

Comment: Yes exactly. But I can even define an array of those words and pass it here but I gotta know what this line means first.  Couldn't understand from the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line is a string following a set of rules of the [JSGF specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/). There is a more "user-friendly" explanation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) on this topic as well.

Basically in this case we can break this down to:

- `#JSGF V1.0;` a header from the specification, always necessary to know which version it should use. Shouldn't change for you.
- `grammar colors;` is a (custom) name of your grammar.
- `public <color> =`  creates a publicly accessible rule called `color`. "Publicly accessible" means your grammar can be imported by someone else and this rule is accessible to them. `color` is the rule name. This is necessary when referring from another rule (example later)
- `aqua | azure | ...` are the options that match this. `|` means "or". So when it recognises one of `aqua`, `azure`, `...`, it matches that `<color>` rule.

A bit more sophisticated example with referencing would be:
`#JSGF V1.0; grammar greeting; <greet> = hello | welcome; <name> = Alice | Bob; public <statement> = <greet> <name>;`

But now to the practicality of this: I've played around with [the MDN Speech Recognition Demo](https://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speech-color-changer/) a bit and I don't think that browsers are really using the grammar (yet). If you have a look into [its source code](https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/blob/master/speech-color-changer/script.js), it will never call the `recognition.onnomatch` function, making the grammar feel a bit useless to me. It also doesn't show up in the results and in the end you only retrieve a transcript of the spoken text - at least in Chrome.

My conclusion to this (mid 2020) is that you do not really need it right now. Maybe it could help in the future but as the [Can I use... table](https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition) (still) looks quite red, I doubt this will be the final way of doing things with speech.