# Improve speech recognition ( web speech api)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, webspeech-api

I'm trying to write a speech recognition program that involves recognizing medical jargon(words like Prozac,Methadone and Vicodin). Now I recently found out that the grammar for the Web Speech API has no practical implementation. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993198/web-speech-api-grammar/62995081#62995081) for additional details.
Is there any way I can make my program be better at handling speech to text recognition in the current case?
Or is there any better alternative or approach I can use for my scenario here?

Comment: Can you please ask a more practical answerable question?  This would require months or years to fully answer (as is).  Thanks.

Comment: More practical as in how? I explained my problem. I need an approach/solution that would better the speech recognition program for understanding particular words. Are you saying that as of now that's not possible? I'm a newbie so bear with me please.

Comment: It's 'possible' -- it's just going to require too much time to answer.  A more concrete question is probably needed.  (See my above comment:  This would require months or years to fully answer (as is). Thanks. )

Comment: A good start would be to put a section of actual code that you need help with